# Variable not updating unless I log it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an odd situation in my Node JS app.
Calling `overrideAndStart()` sets the variable `forceOverride`.
Later calling `checkToStartStop()` it will use that variable.

If you look at my code below, if I comment out the line `THIS LINE HERE 1111` the log of variable `forceOverride` on line `2222` is `false` when it should be `true`. If I leave the log line `1111` in, then the variable at line `2222` is correct `true`.

Obviously I could just leave that log line in and my code works fine, but i'm struggling to understand what is happening here and why logging the variable before comparing it makes it have the correct value.

```
var forceOverride = false;

function overrideAndStart(enable) {
    log('overrideAndStart:' + enable);
    if (enable === 'true') {
        forceOverride = true;
        start(function(result){});
    } else {
        forceOverride = false;
        stop(function(result){});
    }
};
exports.overrideAndStart = overrideAndStart;

function checkToStartStop(returnFunction) {
    eespvo.getSomeData(function(result, error) {
        if (error) {
            returnFunction(new Result(null, null, error));
        } else {
            log(result);
            if (result['exporting'] === true) {
                exporting(result['net'], returnFunction);
            } else {
                importing(result['net'], returnFunction);
            }
        }
    });
};
exports.checkToStartStop = checkToStartStop;

var importing = function(rateW, returnFunction) {
    log('importing - forceOverride===' + forceOverride); // <-- THIS LINE HERE 1111
    areWeCharging(function(charging, error) {
        if (error) {
            lastResult = new Result(null, null, error);
            returnFunction(lastResult);
        } else {
            log('importing - forceOverride=' + forceOverride); // <-- THIS LINE HERE 2222
            if (charging === true) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
};
```

---- EDIT - Log function ----

```
global.mylog = function(prefix, message) {
    debug ? (console.log(new Date().toString() + '\t' + prefix + '\t\t' + ((typeof message === 'string') ? message : util.inspect(message)) )) : null
};

// Logging helper function
var log = function(message)
{
    mylog(__filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1), message);
};
```

Comment: I've just confirmed, it's the same with `console.log` so the `log` function doesn't seem to be relevant. I think the issue is to do with the variable being used before calling the nested function.

Comment: `(enable === 'true')` are you sure about this ? you are comparing string and not a bool.

Comment: Yes you're right, is should be `==` however the right code is being called as the variable is being set to `true` and `start()` function is being called.

Comment: `==` won't do, assuming `enable` actually has a Boolean value. You need `if (enable === true)` (no quotes)

Comment: I'm sending post data `enable=true` so I assume it's a proper boolean. I'll try changing it, however as I said, the correct `start()` function was being called so the variable had changed.

Comment: `if (enable === true)` is false, so it must be interpreted as a string.